# dyld error: image not found

Tags: cocoa-touch, linker, shared-libraries, dyld

I got this error message while running my application on simulator.

> Dyld Error Message:
>
> Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>
> Referenced from: /Users/thomasschober/Excuse Me/build/Distribution-iphonesimulator/Excuse Me.app/Excuse Me
>
> Reason: image not found

I am not able to understand what is problem.
please help me to solve this problem

Thanks to all

Answer (score 9):

I have the same proble. I have tried all the suggestions above, they wont fix my problem.
I finally found the solution:

- Quit Xcode.
- Open the BasketballTeams.xcodeproj folder (either in Finder with control click Show Contents of Package, or cd down into the directory with terminal) and delete the files that begin with your username (i.e Felipe.*)
- delete the build directory
- Open the project again in Xcode and try Build and Run again

Actually I suggest you to reset you simulator and clean all targets as well.
It works for me, you may find the original post here:
http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/83/topics/1095

Comment: Simply quitting Xcode then deleting the *.pbxuser and *.perspectivev3 files worked.

Comment: Make sure your Frameworks are added as 'optional' where required also.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your project 'build' directory and building again, this resolved the problem for me.

I tried re-adding the frameworks mentioned in each error message but this eventually went round in circles with XCode complaining about missing frameworks that I had only just re-added.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this once before. I cleaned the project, reset the simulator, and restarted XCode - this seemed to fix it. I do not know why the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This means you are missing a required framework in Xcode.

Try adding the framework, **UIKit.framework**, then build again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to XCode 3.2.3 today my iPad app displayed the following message in the simulator

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

I can confirm that deleting the build folder (not just cleaning the target) will correct the issue.  Thanks Eddie

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have tried all the suggestions above, they wont fix my problem. I finally found the solution:

if you are using any external libraries. Then add these libraries in your target.

(Project Target -> General -> choose Embedded Binaries -> then add the request library)

Answer (score 0):

I am running XCode 3.2.4 and i saw a similar error.

Cleaning all targets, quit (xcode and simulator) and then start xcode/build again fixed it.